# How to get spinner selected value and store as string in sqlite?

Tags: android, spinner

I want to get the spinner selected value and return it as string to store in sqlite database read the data when needed.

I try the method as below,

```
sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnCategory);      
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> ar = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.category, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
ar.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
sp.setAdapter(ar);
String selection = sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

and get the string extras as below:

```
selection = extras.getString("category");
```

put extras as below:

```
v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(context,ViewItem.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);               

                intent.putExtra("category", category);

            }
        });
```

But I can't get the spinner value that selected, what I get just the first value in Spinner, may I know what wrong with my coding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onItemSelected`

```
 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)

    TextView tv = (TextView)view;
    String selection = tv.getText().toString();   // or you can use the position but I do this to do other things with the TextView 
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
}
```

[Retrieving Spinner values](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html#SelectListener)

And make sure you `implements OnItemSelectedListener` in your `Activity` and set the listener on your `Spinner`

```
sp.setOnItemSelectedSpinner(this);
```

**Note**

You may want to declare `selection` as a member variable so that you can use it other places and assign it here