# Access Spinner value globally

Tags: android, json

**string.xml file**

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">MM</string>
    <string-array name="material_type">
        <item>Raw Material</item>
        <item>Finished Material</item>
        <item>Semi-finished Material</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**mainactivity.java**

```
Spinner s1=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);

  ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                R.array.material_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s1.setAdapter(adapter);
       final String materialType = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
  b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            InputStream is =null;
            String result1 =null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String a = e1.getText().toString();
                String b = e2.getText().toString();
                String c = e3.getText().toString();

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mat", a));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comp", b));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("desc", c));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mattype", materialType));


                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/matmas/create.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    is = entity.getContent();

                    android.util.Log.e("log_tag", "connection success ");

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    android.util.Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result1 = sb.toString();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    android.util.Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
              try

              {
                  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result1);
                  String w = object.getString("re");
                  if(w.equals("Material Details Created successfully"))
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MenuScreen.class);
                      startActivity(i);

                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FILL REQUIRED FIELDS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), w, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Only the first item "Raw Material"is getting stored into mysql database,even if i choose another items. How to access the selected value to be stored to mysql database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get spinner selected value and store as string in sqlite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874653/how-to-get-spinner-selected-value-and-store-as-string-in-sqlite)

Comment: <? php session_start(); ?> <!doctype html></head> <body bgcolor="#000000"></body> </html> when i try to open index.php in server it is showing error 500...what is the problem

Comment: this is the server side error not in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `Spiner` we have `setOnItemSelectedListener`

```
        String temp [];
        Spinner s1=null;
        String materialType;

        temp = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.material_type);
            materialType = s1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.array.material_type, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s1.setAdapter(adapter);


            s1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    materialType= temp[position];

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You Using Set Onclick listener, You need use below interface for any item click or spinner values changes

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener (){

  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
        int pos, long id) {
    // An item was selected. You can retrieve the selected item using
    // parent.getItemAtPosition(pos)
}

public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // Another interface callback
}
});
```

Comment: <? php

session_start();

?>
<!doctype html></head>


<body bgcolor="#000000"></body>

</html> when i try to open index.php in server it is showing error 500...what is the problem